# Get field values in Twig with #markup

Tags: 8, theming

I want the content to be customized by the user, so I created a simple theme and added some fields like background image, color, size etc.

```twig
{% 
    set background_image = content.field_image.0['#markup'] 
%}
{% 
    set size  = content.field_size.0['#markup'] 
%}
{% 
    set background_color  = content.field_background_color.0['#markup'] 
%}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Is it a safe way to get content with #markup?

```twig
{%
  set section = {
    'section_attributes': create_attribute().addClass([
      'section',
      size|clean_class,
      background_color|clean_class,
    ])
    .setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url(' ~ background_image ~ ');' )
  }
%}
```

Is there any other safe way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would be better to use

```
{{ content.field_size.value }}
```

Then twig will automatically get the value from the field.

If you just want to render the field then `{{ content.field_size}}` should be fine.

Hope it helps.